# How can I prove this statement of big o notation?

Tags: math, computer-science, big-o, discrete-mathematics

How to prove this:

```
x^7 = O(x^10)
x^10 = O(x^7)?
```

I couldn't prove this statement.

Comment: Well, if you can't prove it, you might consider the possibility that the statement is false and try to refute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the definition of big-O notation.

```
f ∈ O(g) <=> (∃ x) (∃ c > 0) (∀ y > x) (|f(y)| <= c⋅|g(y)|)
```

The right hand side can be formulated "the quotient `f/g` is bounded for sufficiently large `x`".

So to prove that `f ∈ O(g)`, look at the quotient, choose a (largish) `x` and try to find a bound.
For the first case, the quotient is

```
x⁷ / x¹⁰ = 1/x³
```

A bound for `x ≥ 1` is obvious.

To refute `f ∈ O(g)`, look at the quotient and prove that it assumes values of arbitrarily large modulus on each interval `[x, ∞)`. Assume an arbitrary `c > 0`, and prove that for any `x`, there is an `y > x` with `|f(y)/g(y)| > c`.

That should give enough of a hint.

> If not: `x³ > c` for `x ≥ c+1`.